# Selenium with python - webdriver (chrome browser) crawling website store locator AJAX call failure (but manual open chrome browser is fine)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, frontend, web-crawler

[image]

I have some trouble when doing some control.
I have no idea why manual open chrome browser can do two things in the attached image but using selenium will fail to do that

The two things are:

1. Scroll down can trigger an ajax call and then return more address information
2. click this button can show the detail of the address by ajax call

Comment: I add some additional information:
The image is the browser that created by selenium driver.get(url)

Comment: You can add url to page so we can help you faster